# Port Old Postgresql DB to New Computer

Tags: sql, postgresql

Due to a lightning strike on my house my old computer was recently fried.  But I bought a new one and much to my delight, the C: SSD filesystem from that old machine was still working after I ported it to the new one, albeit now as a D: drive.

Now I'm getting ready to install PostgreSQL and would like to be able to access the old database that resides on the D: drive.  I am stumped as how to proceed.

1. There does not seem to be any way to tell a running PostgreSQL instance, "Hey look over there on the D: drive - that's a data base you can use.  There's a CREATE Database and a DROP database, but not a "Use this database".  I should say I was running version 14 on the old machine and could certainly install that same DB again on the new one before upgrading, if there were a way to add to its catalogue.
2. There is no data base dump/conversion utility that works without going through a running PostgreSQL server instance, so I see no way to convert the old data out of its proprietary format and reload it to the new PostgreSQl instance.
3. The only thought that occurs to me is to install a version as close to the old version 14 as possible, then CREATE a second data base somewhere new (perhaps on the D: drive), then stop the PostgreSQL server instance, copy the old data over top of the new data (with all subdirectories), then restart the server and hope for the best.  Sounds like a 50-50 proposition at best.

Anyone else have any other thoughts/ideas?

Comment: 1) How did you install Postgres on the machine that got installed? 2) How do  you plan to  install the new Postgres? 2) Copy the Postgres data directory to C:\. 4) You can point at the desired data directory using `pg_ctl -D <data_dir>` per [pg_ctl](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pg-ctl.html). This assumes the conf files are in that directory.

Answer (score 0):

So, just in case someone else has this problem and finds this question, here is what I found.

The installer for PostgreSQL has a prompt for what data directory to use.  (After making a backup copy of the data,) I told it to use `D:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\14\data` and it recognized that this was an existing PostgreSQL data repository and it preserved all my tables.

As an experiment afterward I copied the backup data back into the data directory (after stopping the DB), restarted the DB, and everything was fine after PostgreSQL complained a little about the LOG files locations.  I would say this can work as long as you are running the same version of PostgreSQL that last worked with the database on your old computer.